# How to call get attribute from a li tag in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do is similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Barzi/Jzs6B/9/).

When I click on the "Movie A", I hope the function `$('#playlist li').click(function(){...})` will be called, but it seems that nothing happens. What is the problem?

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home Video Player</title>
</head>
<body>      
    <video id="video" width="640" height="320" controls="controls">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>    
    <ul id="playlist">
        <li movieurl="a,mp4" movietype="video/mp4">Movie A</li>
        <li movieurl="b.mp4" movietype="video/mp4">Movie B</li>          
        <li movieurl="c.mp4" movietype="video/mp4">Movie C</li>      
        <li movieurl="d.mp4" movietype="video/mp4">Movie D</li>
    </ul>       
    <script src="main.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#playlist li').click(function(){
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var source = document.createElement('source');
        source.setAttribute('src', $(this).attr("movieurl"));
        source.setAttribute('type', $(this).attr("movietype"));
        video.appendChild(source);
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is your reference to Jquery?

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: ( btw, as you're using JQuery you can replace ``document.getElementById('video');`` by ``$('#video');`` )

Comment: @Maxime Yes, "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Comment: @Tony is right then, you did not import jquery. You need something like ``<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>``

Comment: You need to include **[jQuery reference](https://jquery.com/download/)** before you refer a jQuery code.

Comment: if you have problem only on Movie A. please replace "a,mp4"  to "a.mp4" in your html.  you put "." instead of comma ","

Comment: Thank you very much, I my script can run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use Jquery, you need to link it, here's the CDN link.

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your html `<head>`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't referenced JQuery.

You will most liekly see in a console (Firebug for example) "$ is not defined".. meaning the JQuery "$" object hasn't been created.

To fix this, include a reference to JQuery (either locally or on a CDN)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

should do what you need it to.

Remember that JQuery must be defined BEFORE your script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="main.js"> </script>
```

You can get a correct version of JQuery to use from https://code.jquery.com/jquery/

Also, as others have noted:

- movie,a should probably be movie.a in your bullet list
- You can get elements by using $('#elementid') instead of using getElementById in JQuery - much shorter to type!

Comment: +1 because you suggest to include jQuery libs inside `<body>` before the OP script (better position than in `<head>` for me).

Comment: Thanks Frogmouth.. I've always included in body.. Haven't given it much thought, but its just how I've always done things.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in between your `<head>` tags:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

In order to use jQuery and javascript files, you need to tell your html document that there are JS files that the page's behavior can be interpreted from.

Also, since you are using jQuery, you can replace

```
document.getElementById('video');
```

with

```
$('#video');
```

**EDIT:** I stand corrected, the best practice for scripts is to add them to the end of your body.

Comment: no reason it has to be in head, best practice is at end of body for scripts